# Xcode and installed SF Pro Display( Apple font )

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an [InvisionApp](https://www.invisionapp.com) design with a typeface set to "SF UI Display" & "SF UI Text". I downloaded the font from [apple](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/), with an installer. It installed it in "~/Library/Fonts".

I can understand that if I use "System", then it will use "SF Pro Display". My question is, how can I actively/manually use it - so it will not change accordingly and or together with iOS. I can not find see "SF Pro Display", in Xcode when I choose "Custom" font.

Do you know how to use it? One solution is/could be to add the "otf" file as described [here](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/#includefonts)

But I can see "SF Pro Display" when I use TextEdit and other Mac applications.

Comment: You need to explicitly add these fonts in your source code and add an entry in .plist file.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I installled the apple fonts but cannot find SF Pro Display in interface builder

Comment: Hi - nope, no solution - I ended up just using Systerm in IB.

Comment: same here.......

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to manually choose between those font families (Text & Display), the system will decide which one to use. You can just get the system font which you need (size & weight) and Apple will take care about the rest :) [Here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/804/) is the source, explanation is between 12:30 and 13:30 in the video.